# How to call .sh with pid for a java process on Fedora

Tags: shell-script, fedora, process

I wanted to start a Minecraft-Server. so I've downloaded the `.jar` file, installed java 8, created user and directory like:

```
ls -la
insgesamt 29552
drwxrwxr-x. 4 minecraft minecraft      235 26. Mär 19:32 .
drwx------. 3 minecraft minecraft       97 25. Mär 19:28 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 minecraft minecraft        2 26. Mär 21:16 banned-ips.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 minecraft minecraft        2 26. Mär 21:16 banned-players.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 minecraft minecraft      181 25. Mär 19:22 eula.txt
drwxrwxr-x. 2 minecraft minecraft     4096 26. Mär 21:16 logs
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 minecraft minecraft 30222121 18. Sep 2017  minecraft_server.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 minecraft minecraft        2 26. Mär 21:16 ops.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 minecraft minecraft      754 26. Mär 21:16 server.properties
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 minecraft minecraft      141 26. Mär 21:08 startup-server.sh
-rw-rw-r--. 1 minecraft minecraft      214 26. Mär 21:17 usercache.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 minecraft minecraft        2 25. Mär 19:23 whitelist.json
drwxrwxr-x. 9 minecraft minecraft      166 26. Mär 21:38 world
```

**startup-server.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo I am starting server now
now=$(date +%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S)
/usr/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

**/usr/bin/startup-minecraft-server**:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=Minecraft-Server
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/minecraft-server.pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            exec /home/minecraft/server/startup-server.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
           $0 stop
       $0 start
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    status)
    if [ -e $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            echo minecraft server is running, pid=`cat $PID_PATH_NAME`
    else
            echo minecraft server is NOT running
        exit 1
    fi
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

Whenever I call

```
startup-minecraft-server start
```

It tells me:

```
./startup-minecraft-server start
Starting Minecraft-Server ...
Minecraft-Server started ...
```

and checking on status:

```
./startup-minecraft-server status
minecraft server is running, pid=30639
```

but

```
ps -p 30639 -o comm=
```

results in nothing. 
I do not have a clue why this is happening.

**EDIT:**

I changed the script, but still got the same result as before:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=Minecraft-Server
PATH_TO_JAR=/home/minecraft/server/minecraft_server.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/minecraft-server.pid
case $1 in
    start)
    echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
    if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar $PATH_TO_JAR nogui > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
    fi
    ;;
    stop)
    if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
        kill $PID;
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
        rm $PID_PATH_NAME
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
    fi
    ;;
    restart)
    if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        $0 stop
        $0 start
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
    fi
    ;;
    status)
    if [ -e $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        echo minecraft server is running, pid=`cat $PID_PATH_NAME`
    else
        echo minecraft server is NOT running
    exit 1
    fi
    ;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Please mind the spaces at the end of a line, especially in code blocks.

Comment: There is not a single space

Comment: Because I deleted hundreds of them as you could easily have seen in the editing history.

Comment: Yeah but I checked the script and there was not a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line fixed it:

Deleting the daemon
And adding a > to the echo $!

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar $PATH_TO_JAR nogui > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! >>$PID_PATH_NAME
```

I also did:

```
cd /home/minecraft/server/
pwd
```

at the start of the script

Answer (score 1):

```
exec /home/minecraft/server/startup-server.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!
```

gives you the PID of `startup-server.sh` which exits nearly immediately. But you want the PID of

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

For your approach to work you need

```
exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

In addition `if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]` is not enough. You should always check that the process still exists and that it is the right one.

It may make sense to use something like `startproc` instead.

Comment: That's not really helpful. I do know what the mistake is, or what is not happening.

Comment: @Code.IT That is a really strange comment. I am not even sure I understand it. In any case it does not sound like you want help.

Comment: I tried all of the above. No results

Answer (score 0):

This `PID` returned from `/home/minecraft/server/startup-server.sh` script (new bash process). You need to get `PID` from this command `/usr/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui`.

Comment: That's not really helpful. I do know what the mistake is, or what is not happening.

Comment: Try to start process as daemon without `exec`. I think this no need `exec` command.

Comment: I also tried this, still doesn't work

Comment: Please try to start `/usr/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui &` directly. What's result?